# How to run Jscript Script file on Task Scheduler Windows Script Host

Tags: javascript, windows

I try to run this doit.js Javascript on Task Scheduler on windows 7

When I execute manually, I meant without using task Scheduler, This script is working.

When I execute manually/click. there are windows said "Windows Script Host" and also appreared the icon of windows script Host in the bottom of screen.

Therefore, I assume that cscript.exe or wscript.exe

Right Click the task, Click Properties---> Click "Action" ---->Click "Edit"

I browse in "Program/Script"

C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe

or

C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe

I tried both and

I Copied and Pasted in "Add argument(optional)"

C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\doit.js

but it is not working, How can I set in Task Scheduler to run this script?

Answer (score 2):

SO I found out

I added

C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe                   on "Program/Script"

C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\doit.js          on  "Add argument(optional)"

C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\                 on "Start in(optional)"

I hope this question help someone

Comment: This helped me, much obliged